# default value with ajax on jqgrid

Tags: php, html, ajax, jqgrid

I'm using phpGrid library based on jqgrid and I have this function:

```
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        var grid = $(this); 

        if(id && id!==lastSel){               
             grid.restoreRow(lastSel);   
             lastSel = id;
             var rd = jQuery("#php_temp_det_vo").jqGrid("getCell", id, "status");

             if(rd == 1){
                  alert("Data cannot be changed");
                  $("#'. $this->jq_gridName .'").trigger("reloadGrid");
             }
             else{
                  $(function(){ $("#begin_km").val("123"); });
             }
        }
        grid.editRow(id, true,oneditfunc,"","","",aftersavefunc);
    }
```

I need to dynamically give default value to one column called begin_km depends on some function that I will generate later. I wanted to try `$(function(){ $("#begin_km").val("123"); });` first without that function I mentioned, but it doesn't work whereas it works on a simple html page:

the ajax

```
$(function(){ $("#aaa").val("123"); });
```

the html

```
<input type="text" id="aaa" />
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

**EDITED:**
Here's a slice of my jqgrid column model *refering to begin_id as column ID

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    colModel:[{"name":"id","id":"id","index":"id","hidden":true},
    {"name":"begin_km","id":"begin_km","index":"begin_km","hidden":false,"align":"right"},
    ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the cell values using `setCell`

onSelectRow: function(id){
        var grid = $(this);

```
    if(id && id!==lastSel){               
         grid.restoreRow(lastSel);   
         lastSel = id;
         var rd = jQuery("#php_temp_det_vo").jqGrid("getCell", id, "status");

         if(rd == 1){
              alert("Data cannot be changed");
              $("#'. $this->jq_gridName .'").trigger("reloadGrid");
         }
         else{

          grid.jqGrid('setCell', id, 'begin_km', "123");
         }
    }
    grid.editRow(id, true,oneditfunc,"","","",aftersavefunc);
}
```

Comment: Try `$("#begin_km").text("123");`  Is `begin_km` the id of a table cell?

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much! Why couldn't I think of that! I got the value of the status with that code, so I should've just reversed it when it comes to assigning value to begin_km